# How to fix Outlook/Hotmail HTML Email Template ignore <br /> and <p> in preview

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, hotmail

I've build some html emails template for our compagny and Outlook "named Hotmail before" when the customer preview is email, no CSS class is preview.

All < p >, < br / >, padding, margin, are not formated.

Is there any solution for fixing that?

My template are build with responsive css class, and also are in HTML Strict 1.0 which is now the standard for Outlook inbox requirements.

See my preview: [image: Email received]

Normally, my email template look like this:

[image: Original Design]

Here are the HTML code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <title>SuprA-Z Web Confirmation Order - Thank You for your order. </title>
    <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->
    <!-- Please use an inliner tool to convert all CSS to inline as inpage or external CSS is removed by email clients -->
    <!-- important in CSS is used to prevent the styles of currently inline CSS from overriding the ones mentioned in media queries when corresponding screen sizes are encountered -->

    <!-- CSS Reset -->
    <style type="text/css">
/* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
      /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
html,  body {
 margin: 0 !important;
 padding: 0 !important;
 height: 100% !important;
 width: 100% !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
* {
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
/* What it does: Forces Outlook.com to display emails full width. */
.ExternalClass {
 width: 100%;
}
/* What is does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
 margin: 0 !important;
}
/* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
table,  td {
 mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
 mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
}
/* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
table {
 border-spacing: 0 !important;
 border-collapse: collapse !important;
 table-layout: fixed !important;
 margin: 0 auto !important;
}
table table table {
 table-layout: auto;
}
/* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
img {
 -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
/* What it does: Overrides styles added when Yahoo's auto-senses a link. */
.yshortcuts a {
 border-bottom: none !important;
}
/* What it does: Another work-around for iOS meddling in triggered links. */
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
 color: inherit !important;
}
</style>

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements -->
    <style type="text/css">
        
        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #555555 !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid,
            .fluid-centered {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .fluid-centered {
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }
        
            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }
   .defined {
    float: right;
   }
   
   .defined:after {
    content: "...";
   }
                
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#222222" width="100%" style="margin: 0;" yahoo="yahoo">
    <table bgcolor="#222222" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
      <tr>
        <td><center style="width: 100%;">
            
            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
            
            <div style="display:none;font-size:1px;line-height:1px;max-height:0px;max-width:0px;opacity:0;overflow:hidden;mso-hide:all;font-family: sans-serif;">
            Your SuprA-Z order is on the way! - Shipping Confirmation Status </div>
            <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END --> 
            
            <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
            <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center"><a href="http://catalog.supraz2000.com/catalog-1/" target="_blank"><img src="https://www.supraz2000.com/garasoft/logo_supra-z_en.png" width="303" height="90" alt="SuprA-Z, Your Auto Parts from A to Z!" style="border:0px"></a><br />
                
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
            <!-- Email Header : END --> 
            <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600" class="email-container">
            
            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td class="full-width-image">
                <div style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; text-align:center; font-family:sans-serif;">
                  <h2 style="color:#4B8EF7;">Your order has been shipped !</h2>
                  <table width="200" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="background-color:#EBEBEB; border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td style="padding:5px; border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                        <span style="text-shadow:#FFFFFF 1px 1px; color:#000000; font-size:14px;">Order Number<br /><span style="color:#4B8EF7; text-shadow:#FFFFFF 1px 1px; font-size:1.75em;">[ORDER_NUMBER]</span></span>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>

                </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : END --> 
            
            <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
              <td style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 40px; padding-right: 40px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #555555;"><p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.15em;">Hi [NOM_CLIENT],</p>
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.15em;">Your order has been shipped on [SHIP_DATE] with the following carrier [CARRIER_NAME].</p>
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.15em;">You can track your order two ways :</p>
                <p style="margin-bottom:5px; text-align:left; font-size:1.15em;"><strong>By calling</strong> the carrier [CARRIER_NAME] with these information :</p>
                <br />
                <table width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" style="background-color:#EBEBEB; border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td style="background-color:#EBEBEB; border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; padding:10px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;" class="stack-column"><font color="#000000">Phone number</font><br>
                          <strong style="font-size:1.25pc;">[TRACKING_PHONE]</strong></td>
                          <td style="background-color:#777777; padding:10px; border-radius: 10px; -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px; vertical-align:top; width:100%;" class="stack-column"><span style="font-size:1pc; color:#FFFFFF;">With your tracking number</span> <br>
                          <span style="font-size:1.25pc;color:#FFFFFF; text-shadow:#000000 1px 1px;">[TRACKING_NO]</span></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                </table>
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.15em;"><strong>By internet</strong> with the following automated Internet URL :<br>
                  <a href="[TRACKING_URL]"><strong>Please track my order</strong></a></p>
                <p style="text-align:left; font-size:1.15em;">Thank you for Trusting <strong>Supr<span style="color:red">A-Z</span></strong>!</p></td>
                </tr>
            <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN --> 
   
            
            <!-- Background Image with Text : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td background="https://www.supraz2000.com/garasoft/Image_600x230.png" bgcolor="#222222" valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;"><!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:175px; background-position: center center !important;">
                    <v:fill type="tile" src="https://www.supraz2000.com/garasoft/Image_600x230.png" color="#222222" />
                    <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                    <![endif]-->
                
               <div>
                    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 20px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 16px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 20px; color: #ffffff; text-shadow:#000000 1px 1px;">
                        <p style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color:hsla(54,100%,50%,1.00); margin-top:0px !important;">SUPRAZ2000 are now becoming :</p>
                        <strong style="font-size:20px;"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;">Supr<span style="color:red;">A-Z</span>, Your Auto Parts From A to Z</span></strong><br>
                <span class="mobile-link--footer">1170 Ste-Foy Blvd., Longueuil, QC, J4K 1W9<br />
                <span style="color:#FFFFFF;">Tel.</span> 1 877 999-0080 · <span style="color:#FFFFFF;">Fax.</span> 450 670-0449 <br />
                <p style="font-size:12px;">
                <img src="https://www.supraz2000.com/garasoft/iconmonstr-email-10-240.png" alt="Email Icon" width="15" height="15"> <a href="mailto:info@supraz2000.com" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Email Us</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="https://www.supraz2000.com/garasoft/iconmonstr-facebook-4-240.png" alt="Facebook Icon" width="15" height="15" style="color:hsla(0,0%,100%,1.00);"> <a href="https://www.facebook.com/supraz2000" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;">SuprA-Z</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="https://www.supraz2000.com/garasoft/iconmonstr-globe-6-240.png" alt="Website Icon" width="15" height="15"> <a href="http://catalogue.supraz2000.com/catalog-1/vehicle" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Website</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="https://www.supraz2000.com/garasoft/iconmonstr-newspaper-4-240.png" alt="Infolettre Icon" width="15" height="15"> <a href="http://catalogue.supraz2000.com/catalog-1/infolettre.wws" target="_blank" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Newsletter</a> </p>
                </span>
                </td>
                      </tr>
                  </table>
                  </div>
                
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                    </v:textbox>
                    </v:rect>
                    <![endif]--></td>
              </tr>
            <!-- Background Image with Text : END --> 
            
          </table>
            <!-- Email Body : END --> 
            
            <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
            <table align="center" width="600" class="email-container">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 10px 10px;width: 100%;font-size: 12px; font-family: sans-serif; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height:18px; text-align: center; color: #888888;">
                <unsubscribe style="color:#888888; text-decoration:underline;"><a href="#" style="color:#D0D0D0;" target="_blank">Unsubscribe</a></unsubscribe>
                </td>
              </tr>
          </table>
            <!-- Email Footer : END -->
          </center></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added HTML code snipped.   Thanks

Comment: Many client, like gmail, not read style in head section. This is only for modern email client link mail in mac or mobile. Gmail anyway ignore <br>. For major compatibility you have to use inline style.

Comment: Hi @Germano, did you had a reference where i can use inline style for responsive? thanks.

Comment: You can't use media query inline unfortunately. Simply many client don't have this functionality. https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/guides/mobile/

Comment: Thanks for the information. I've use in-line CSS coding for the H1,H2 titles. but for table radius, no solution yet.

Comment: Does anyone has a solution for table radius for in-line css fix?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it. I've added pre-style in the header and except 
 I've added \n.

```
pre {
        white-space: pre-line !important;
        font-family: your-font !important;
    }
<pre>Your text. \n Your second line text.</pre>
```